# How to make Fscalender previous month and next month with button action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

Hi use `FSCalender` in my application.

I take two buttons previous and next with those button actions I want customise.

Calendar don't allow expired Days.

I write following code it will working fine but when I am trying to wrong attempts in previous button on the same number of attempts not working on next button also.

```
@IBOutlet weak var calendarView: FSCalendar!

private var currentPage: Date?

private lazy var today: Date = {
    return Date()
}()
private func moveCurrentPage(moveUp: Bool) {

      let calendar = Calendar.current
      var dateComponents = DateComponents()
      dateComponents.month = moveUp ? 1 : -1

      self.currentPage = calendar.date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: self.currentPage ?? self.today)
            calenderView.setCurrentPage(self.currentPage!, animated: true)
  }
```

I use that common method in both cases.

```
@IBAction func calender_BackkBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        self.moveCurrentPage(moveUp: false)
 }

 @IBAction func calender_ForwardBtn(_ sender: Any) {   
        self.moveCurrentPage(moveUp: true)
  }
```

Comment: What you want to customize with Previous and Next Button?

Comment: pick on next button move next month , pick on previous button move to previous.